# Removing whitespaces in string representation of the list in Python

Tags: python, string, list, whitespace

In this Python code

```
def addToArrayForm(num,k):
    num_string = ""
    answer = []
    for n in num:
        num_string += str(n)
    num_string = int(num_string) + k    # This is an integer
    for i in str(num_string):
        answer.append(int(i))
    print(answer)

addToArrayForm([1,2,0,0], 34)
```

I get this output => `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

How can I turn this output `[1, 2, 3, 4]` to this => `[1,2,3,4]` (what i wanna do is to remove these spaces between items)?

Comment: `",".join(str(number) for number in list_of_numbers)`. then you just have to surround that with `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` method.

```py
>>> answer = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(answer)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> newanser = str(answer).replace(' ', '')
>>> print(newanser)
[1,2,3,4]
```

Good luck in leetcode ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to join all elements of `answer` with a comma, and then surround it in brackets. Let's do that!

```
def addToArrayForm(num,k):
    num_string = ""
    answer = []
    for n in num:
        num_string += str(n)
    num_string = int(num_string) + k    # This is an integer
    for i in str(num_string):
        answer.append(int(i))


    # print(answer)
    # Convert each element of answer to string, then join them all by comma
    answer_s = ",".join(str(i) for i in answer) # 1,2,3,4
    # Format answer_s into a string, surround it by brackets, print
    print(f"[{answer_s}]")
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZZBBCsIwEEX3PcWQbhIaRK0roQs3nqC7UiTQtI3SSUkjIuLZY9KgFQ1ZzAz/v5/JeLe9xty5RrYgmqbUB2PE/ajNQPE68AvbJ@CPr0@TNQo7KICQeSZwuknj@6qe@1YbQFAYxNH148wK8BVF9o9UaOkyYJDBJWhSKHs1gb8ikK3spPlkqZA1AxfjkhtftxLjKLGhga9YDE5hNKGPCva1y2kK23GyOmuFNKAVW6K@9ZHQkurxdj5rwpLk5wurDd/yNV/XHPIdc@4F)

Answer (score 0):

Your entire script can be reduced as below.

Working backwards through the list, start with `k` and increase with d * (powers of 10).

`ex: k + 0*1 + 0*10 + 2*100 + 1*1000`

```
def addToArrayForm(num,k):
    for i,d in enumerate(num[::-1]):
        k += d*((10**i) or 1) 
    
    #reformat as you requested
    k = f"[{','.join(str(k))}]"
    
    print(k)

addToArrayForm([1,2,0,0], 34) #[1,2,3,4]
```

One thing to note is: You initially have a `list` and the spaces you are trying to get rid of are just how a `list` is printed. ALL of the answers are converting your `list` to a `str`, in order to provide the result you requested. This ignores your `list`. You may want to consider that spaces being printed in your console isn't affecting anything, and jumping through hoops just to get rid of them is a waste of effort. You end up with something that looks like a `list` in the console, but isn't a `list`, at all.

All that being said: If you decide to keep the results that you already have, but want to get to those results in a much cleaner way, you can do this:

```
def addToArrayForm(num,k):
    for i,d in enumerate(num[::-1]):
        k += d*((10**i) or 1)
    
    #reformat to list
    num = list(map(int, str(k)))
    
    print(num)

addToArrayForm([1,2,0,0], 34)
```